# How do I add English-UK thesaurus and other locales to LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, language-support, localization

I have been trying to use **English-UK thesaurus** in LibreOffice but so far cannot get it to work. I have installed `mythes-en-us` as only it was available in repos. As suggested in some forums I searched for openoffice.org thesaurus, but again US version was available. As a result I can't enable thesaurus when I choose English UK:

[image: LibreOffice Prefs 1]

[image: LibreOffice Prefs 2]

As [instructed elsewhere](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openoffice.org-dictionaries/+bug/950949) I tried this:

```
cd /usr/share/myspell/dicts
sudo ln -s th_en_US_v2.dat th_en_GB_v2.dat
sudo ln -s th_en_US_v2.idx th_en_GB_v2.idx
```

Still the result is same as shown in above screenshots.

What can be done now?

Comment: i am trying to create a more general question on the matter (http://askubuntu.com/q/223557/47206) but my question was closed as duplicate of this here. could you edit yours so as to make it applicable to other languages too? then i could leave mine closed and add more answers here

Comment: @Tom Brossman, please see above comment. also, could you consider editing this one in this respect, or otherwise vote to reopen mine?

Comment: @cipricus I only learned enough about this issue to produce the below answer. I don't know how to improve it to make it more general. I agree that a more general answer would be best, so please edit mine if you know how. I also just voted to re-open the other one (now showing 4 of five needed votes), if that is best for you.

Answer (score 18):

Here's what worked for me. I found most of these steps [in this blog post](http://www.astarix.co.uk/2012/06/proper-british-language-tools-libreoffice/), credit to the author for figuring this out.

1. Download the spelling/hyphen/thesaurus dictionaries you want from LibreOffice's [extensions download page](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/american-british-canadian-spelling-hyphen-thesaurus-dictionaries).
2. Install them in LibreOffice Tools -> Extension Manager -> Add and then close LibreOffice.
3. `sudo apt-get install libmythes-1.2-0 hunspell`
4. `sudo apt-get install mythes-en-us hunspell-en-us`
5. `cd /usr/share/mythes/`
6. `sudo ln -s th_en_US_v2.idx th_en_GB_v2.idx`
7. `sudo ln -s th_en_US_v2.dat th_en_GB_v2.dat`
8. Open LibreOffice Writer and go to Tools -> Options -> Language Settings -> Writing Aids.
9. Verify the new thesaurus is selected, then from Writer test it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to bring up the thesaurus dialogue.

[image: Language settings with new thesaurus]

[image: Functioning UK thesaurus dialogue]

Comment: this should be set as definitive answer

Comment: For Australian English, use `sudo ln -s th_en_US_v2.idx th_en_AU_v2.idx` and `sudo ln -s th_en_US_v2.dat th_en_AU_v2.dat`.

Answer (score 8):

This latest version of the Libreoffice Extension "English Dictionaries" works with the latest version of Libreoffice and will hopefully get the thesaurus activated for you.

http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/english-dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

With each installation of Libreoffice on any of the Distros I have installed for myself or others I have found that the thesaurus always works after I have installed the [English dictionaries for Apache OpenOffice-2013.07.31](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/projectrelease/english-dictionaries-apache-openoffice-20130731) rather than any extension from LibreOffice.

This makes all the above solutions unnecessary.

This OpenOffice dictionary extension is a year old now and although there are more recent versions here [English dictionaries for Apache OpenOffice](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/english-dictionaries-apache-openoffice) they always give the error

> Extension requires at least OpenOffice.org reference version 4.0

when I attempt to install them.

Answer (score 1):

- **For English-UK**, the correct answer is in [Mik](https://askubuntu.com/users/76204/mik)'s

I am posting this answer for other locales:

So:

- For **French**, go [here](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/dictionnaires-francais) to get the French dictionary and install in LibreOffice Writer in Tools-Extensions manager. (The spelling works before installing that, but synonyms context menu does not).

Answer (score 0):

JosephWheatley's answer led me into the right direction: spelling packages are maintained by different people and so the names are pretty different. While en-us packages exist in many variations, this is not for en-gb, so you don't find the right packages by accident. So I searched `aptitude` for `*-en-gb` in every category (dictionary, thesaurus, hyphenation) and after installation libreoffice showed en-gb as spellcheck opportunity! :)

`sudo aptitude install myspell-en-gb libreoffice-grammarcheck-en-gb mythes-en-gb`

works for me on Debian Jessie (because it is Testing it is similar to Ubuntu). The last 2 packages are metapackages (and thus are not! autocompleted nor shown as installed when filtering by `~i` for me) and they are linking to

- libreoffice-lightproof-en
- mythes-en-us