# Thesaurus in LibreOffice 5.3

Tags: libreoffice

I do not have access to Thesaurus in LibreOffice 5.3
I tried following the instructions at [this AskUbuntu article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85752/how-to-install-a-thesaurus-in-libreoffice)
but I do not have such a thing.
I cannot install the openoffice link suggested below.  It is not found

```
sudo apt-get install openoffice.org-thesaurus-en-us
```

I installed libreoffice using the ppa.
This is what I see for my "writing aids" screenshot which is different than the other article.  Clicking on get more dictionaries yields nothing.

[image: writing aids from libreoffice]

Comment: In 5.3 you do not have to install anything extra, it should be there. 1) When you right-click a word, do you not see a menu that has Synonyms at the bottom?  2) If not, is US English the language you are using?

Comment: nope.  I don't have that option.  It is gray.  Spell checker works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably still need to install the thesaurus as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install mythes-en-us
```

And don't forget to enable it under:

Tools > Options > Language Settings > Writing Aids