# How to set LibreOffice to suggest corrections for UK English?

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, libreoffice, language-support

I want to be given correction suggestions while setting a text in LibreOffice to English-UK.

[image]

Now it works for English-US, French and Romanian, as these are the languages that I have installed in Language Support. I cannot seem to have a setting to differentiate US/UK English as I was able in Xubuntu.

[image]

In LibreOffice English-UK is absent. How to add it?

[image]

In `Tools/Options/Language Settings/Languages` I get to the image above, but how to make English UK present there? it lacks that 'ABC-V' sign that is present for English USA, although in `Tools/Options/Language Settings/Writing Aids` an 'English-uk' IS PRESENT. But that is not enough for the corrector to function for English-UK.

Comment: accepted answer in a duplicate question, https://askubuntu.com/a/935170/197730, is short and sweet and worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem with a fresh installation of Lubuntu. I set everything that I could to English (UK), but spell checking did not work. I eventually found this:

[Cannot set language for spell check](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/78224/cannot-set-language-for-spell-check/)

I fixed the problem by opening a terminal and typing:

```
sudo apt-get install hunspell-en-gb
```

and entering my password when prompted.

The red squiggly underlines finally appeared in my document.

As it has already been said, the previous solution does not work because of a dead link.

Comment: this is what works in 2018

Answer (score 7):

It's pretty straightforward to setup British spell checking- I did it a while ago as I am in the UK, so it's pretty important for me. My version of `Libreoffice` is exactly the same as yours: the default 3.5.x series version for 12.04.

For some reason this UK dictionary isn't included with the Ubuntu packaged version, even though it is when you download it on Windows and the UK spell checking is enabled.

Please go to [the official list of dictionaries](http://www.libreoffice-na.us/KPP-dictionaries/dictionary.html) and choose **kpp-british-english-dictionary** and download it to your desktop or downloads folder. Now open that downloaded file with `LibreOffice` itself and you will be presented with this screen:

[image]

Now, make sure that it is enabled, and restart `Libreoffice` and open Writer, select English UK and it will auto highlight your mistakes as below, as long as the other settings are set to English UK in Tools > Options > Language Settings > Languages.

Also, it is important to make sure `AutoSpellCheck` is enabled.

[image]

On getting **also thesaurus/synonyms**, there is already [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/196117/47206).

Comment: hello again! do you know how to activate synonyms context menu in uk english too? (http://askubuntu.com/q/223557/47206)

Comment: @cipricus I'll have a look and see what I can do.

Comment: thesaurus/synonyms - http://askubuntu.com/a/196117/47206

Comment: The link to "official dictionaries" is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your issue is bigger, but from the LibreOffice menu bar:

Tools --> Options --> Language Settings

and then play around with the two sub-menus (Languages and Writing Aids)

Comment: In Language Settings/Language  i get to the image above, but how to make English UK present there? you see it lacks that 'abcV' that is present for English USA, although in Language Settings/Writing Aids an'English-uk' IS PRESENT. But that is not enough for the corrector to function for uk English

Comment: what version of libreoffice are you using?

Comment: LibreOffice 3.5.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Update:

The simplest way to enable British spell checking in LibreOffice on recent Ubuntu versions is to install the hunspell-en-gb package.

sudo apt install hunspell-en-gb

from https://askubuntu.com/a/935170/307670

Answer (score -1):

How to set LibreOffice ‘Language-Settings’ to UK-English
Trying to get English–en-gb with….
        Thesaurus/Spellcheck/Hyphenation/Grammar all working!
Go to Tools > Options > Language Settings > Languages.. I that window,
under ‘Language Of’ > User interface:   Select “English (UK)” and below that,
under ‘Default Language for Documents’ > Western:   Select “English (UK)”.
NOTE the “ ABC√ ” sign that is in front of English (UK). (it may be missing!)
I get to the image above in  Tools/Options/Language Settings/Languages
Next open  Tools/Options/Language Settings/Writing Aids….
Edit the “Hunspell Spellchecker”,  Select “English (UK)”.

NOTE the “ ABC√ ” sign that is in front of English (UK). (it may be missing!)

BUT if  the “ ABC√ ” sign is NOT in front of English (UK), If it’s missing, then…
The English UK dictionary isn't included with the Ubuntu packaged version of LibreOffice, even though it is when you download it on Windows and the UK spell checking is enabled.

Open LibreOffice Writer and go to…..
Tools -> Options -> Language Settings -> Writing Aids. 
Verify the new Thesaurus is selected, by pressing Ctrl + F7 to bring up the thesaurus dialogue.

To be sure, to be sure, I went to this Web site…. 
(for ALL English Dictionary extensions) http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/english-dictionaries

I flicked down to….  English Dictionaries 2016.04.01   see script above.
There, I ‘clicked’ on “ English Dictionaries 2016.04.01 ” and downloaded/Save this File.. “dict-en.oxt”.
NEXT, go to this Web site…. 
To get “kpp-british-english-dictionary-674039-word-list.oxt” 
 and Downloaded/Save the File.
British English- en_GB

The following "kpp" dictionaries can be all installed, then enabled/disabled to select the one you want to use with/for your documents.

kpp-british-english-dictionary-674039-word-list.oxt 674,039 word list, hyphen, and thesaurus - November-2012 
http://www.libreoffice-na.us/KPP-dictionaries/dictionary.html
NOW, Go to your 2 Downloaded files, Click on each one separately. 
CHOOSE open with LibreOffice. ‘Extension Manager’ will be activated, If the files ar already installed you can clic-on ‘Cancel’, otherwise ckoose “OK” and install both.
That’s about it!!!

### you should have Thesaurus and the ALL rest...

P.S.
2016-04-07 and there are still problems with English UK on ubuntu-Linux.
'The Queen's English' is still not FULLY available.
Not on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (Trusty Tahr),  Not on UbuntuMATE 15.10(Wily Werewolf)-UbuntuMATE 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)and so on and so on, why?
It's a nuisance to say the least.