# British Spellcheck in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, settings, language-support, spell-checking

How do I set LibreOffice to spellcheck in British English? When I set it to BE now, it doesn't spellcheck anything. I'm using the latest LibreOffice in Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: How did you set it ?

Comment: Have you installed the `hunspell-en-gb` package?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Options > Language Settings > Languages. Regarding your marking my question as duplicate, the dictionaries listed in the first answer are from 2012 and there are no British English dictionary extensions in the link that the last answer gave. The middle answer is what I already did.

Comment: As your google is broken, dictionaries here - https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/english-dictionaries . This is a duplicate as explained in the link I indicated, British dictionary is NOT included in the ubuntu package and must be downloaded fro libreoffice site. @GunnarHjalmarsson - As far as I know, libreoffice uses its own dictionaries and not hunspell

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: What's packaged in `hunspell-en-gb` is precisely those LO extensions. Its source package is [libreoffice-dictionaries](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice-dictionaries). So there is no reason to point users to the LO site for this purpose.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson - So you should post that as an answer rather then a comment.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Done.

Comment: since this one has the updated answer now, I am voting to close the other one as a duplicate of this one

Comment: @Zanna: Too late unless we reopen this one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way to enable British spell checking in LibreOffice on recent Ubuntu versions is to install the `hunspell-en-gb` package.

```
sudo apt install hunspell-en-gb
```