# how to share jisti meet room url/link to users?

Tags: 18.04

I am new to jisti-meet I install it and its working fine, now I want to share the link of room to users so that they login with password, so how to set the password of the room and how to share the url / link to people. Thank you

Comment: It seems to me jitsi-meet does not allow password protected rooms. You may restrict who can create a room to those who have registered and have a password. But once someone create a room, anyone who knows the URL can enter the meeting room.

Comment: After you start the meeting, you can click on the shield icon at the bottom right of the screen to add a password to your meeting.

Comment: I, on the other hand, am not actually sure what this question has to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: @KGIII I understand your point. My take is, since the jitsi-meet server is running on an Ubuntu server, it is a question about an "app" that runs on Ubuntu, just like how to do [spell check in LibreOffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216759/how-to-set-libreoffice-to-suggest-corrections-for-uk-english) in the desktop context. So, I think it is on-topic. The problem is, the question could use some more details, as it is not clear what OP wants, and if it can be done at all.

Comment: how to terminate or delete all the rooms.