# How to install, select and use different keyboard layouts of the same language in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout, language-support

In Lubuntu's Language Support application I see no way of differentiating between different types of the same language (English US, UK, etc) nor between different types of keyboard layouts for the same language (standard, etc). To select a certain special keyboard layout I had to edit manually `/etc/default/keyboard`.

All that was possible by GUI when I used Xubuntu, and I think all that is available in Ubuntu proper.

Can I do that in Lubuntu or do I have to install a new application?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- **In order to install different languages** that are to be used by the system, Lubuntu has the Ubuntu Default Language Manager.

This should be easily accessed through the Preferences>Language Support. Check here to see if the application is installed.

```
/usr/bin/gnome-language-selector
```

Chosen Language
[image]

[image] Regional Support

If you do not see nor can confirm the application is installed then open a terminal and install it by using the following command `sudo apt-get install language-selector-gnome`

Once installed you will have access to all the major Language/Regional formats

The maintainer is ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com

- **In order to chose between different types of keyboard for the same language** -

  Be sure Keyboard Layout Handler is visible in the LXPanel. If not, right click on the lxpanel, "Add/remove panel items" and add it. Then edit it. If it is already visible, right click on it and select "Keyboard Layout Handler" Settings.

[image]

[image]

Then click "Add"

[image]

*Another alternative would be KDE

```
sudo apt-get install language-selector-kde
```

I would advise you that this also brings a lot of other (maybe unwanted) dependencies.

Comment: For 16.04 you may be looking for Keyboard Layout Handler... It is in Indicator applets....