# Synonyms for different languages in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I add English-UK thesaurus in LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42850/how-do-i-add-english-uk-thesaurus-in-libreoffice)

When setting a text for English US the context menu contains 'Synonyms'

[image]

This is not the case for the other languages for which I have the spelling installed (English UK, French etc)

Can I have the Synonyms option for UK English too, for example? Even that is a problem although there seems to be solutions around for it. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/42879/47206), for example, (which is a link to [here](http://www.weeklywhinge.com/?p=69)) but after testing it cannot see synonyms for uk.

**What about other languages**?

---

Please notice that this question is not just about English-UK. I have initially noticed that 'synonyms' where missing in relation to British, but **I am asking about how to solve the issue in general or, when there is no general solution, how to solve it on a case-by-case basis**. For the meta consequence of all this, involving the issue of it being a duplicate, see comments under [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5460/47206) and these meta questions, [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5467/47206) and [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5468/47206). The British-related question to which this was flagged as duplicate involves a particular bug and therefore its solution cannot be appropriate to a question that goes beyond that particular case.)

Comment: The solution posted on [this blog](http://www.astarix.co.uk/2012/06/proper-british-language-tools-libreoffice/) as explained in Tom's [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42850/how-do-i-add-english-uk-thesaurus-in-libreoffice/196117#196117)  does work for me.